# How to remove the tab delimiter after the last column by using unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a tab separated file. I am using the below code:

```
awk -v var="MAS_CONTROL_WL_column_nmbr.dat" 'BEGIN{RS="\n"}
{ while(getline line < var){ printf("%s\t",$line)};close(var);
printf( "\n") }' MAS_CONTROL_WL.tsv > test.tsv
```

This code prints the column number that is present in the column number file but the issue that I am facing is `\t` is coming after the last column.
How to remove that?

Comment: Show some sample data would be better, whats in the column_nmber file, and what's in the tsv file. Also what's your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing "field-tab" for every field, print the first field without a tab, then append the rest as "tab-field":

```
awk -v var="MAS_CONTROL_WL_column_nmbr.dat" '
    BEGIN{RS="\n"}
    {
        if (getline line < var) printf("%s",$line);
        while (getline line < var) printf("\t%s",$line);
        close(var);
        printf( "\n");
    }
' MAS_CONTROL_WL.tsv > test.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

First a test file:

```
$ cat > foo
1
2
3
```

And the awk:

```
$ awk -v var=foo '
BEGIN { RS="\n" }
{ 
    out=""                                              # introducing output buffer
    while(getline line < var) {
        out=out sprintf("%s%s",(out==""?"":"\t"),line)  # controlling tabs
    }
    close(var)
    print out                                           # output output buffer
}' foo | cat -T                                         # useful use of cat
```

Output:

```
1^I2^I3
1^I2^I3
1^I2^I3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need an answer to your original question (removing \t after the last column) :`sed -i 's/[[:space:]]$//' your_file.tsv` will remove the white space at the end of the lines of your file.